# Resolving Dependencies in JNI DefineClass

Tags: java, jvm, java-native-interface, jvmti

I am writing an application using the JVMTI. I am trying to instrument the bytecode: by injecting method calls on every method entry.

I know how to do that, but the problem is in the instrument class, say it's called `Proxy`, which I load using the JNI function DefineClass. My `Proxy` has a few dependencies in Java Class Library, currently just `java.lang.ThreadLocal<Boolean>`.

Now, say I have this, where `inInstrumentMethod` is a plain `boolean`:

```
public static void onEntry(int methodID)
{
    if (inInstrumentMethod) {
        return;
    } else {
        inInstrumentMethod = true;
    }

    System.out.println("Method ID: " + methodID);

    inInstrumentMethod = false;
}
```

The code compiles and works. However, if I make `inInstrumentMethod` a `java.lang.ThreadLocal<Boolean>`, I get a NoClassDefFoundError. The code:

```
private static ThreadLocal<Boolean> inInstrumentMethod = new ThreadLocal<Boolean>() {
        @Override protected Boolean initialValue() {
            return Boolean.FALSE;
        }
    };

public static void onEntry(int methodID)
{
    if (inInstrumentMethod.get()) {
        return;
    } else {
        inInstrumentMethod.set(true);
    }

    System.out.println("Method ID: " + methodID);

    inInstrumentMethod.set(false);
}
```

My guess is that the dependencies have not been resolved correctly, and `java.lang.ThreadLocal` was not loaded (and thus could not be found). The question is, then, how do I force Java to load `java.lang.ThreadLocal`? I don't think I could use `DefineClass` in this case; is there an alternative?

Comment: You get `NoClassDefFoundError` for what class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t think that there is a problem resolving the standard class `java.lang.ThreadLocal`, but rather with the inner class extending it, generated by

```
new ThreadLocal<Boolean>() {
    @Override protected Boolean initialValue() {
        return Boolean.FALSE;
    }
};
```

Solving this via `DefineClass` might indeed be impossible due to the circular dependency between the inner and outer class, so there’s no order which allows to define them, unless you have a full-fledged `ClassLoader` that returns the classes on demand.

The simplest solution is to avoid the generation of an inner class at all, which is possible with Java 8:

```
private static ThreadLocal<Boolean> inInstrumentMethod
                                  = ThreadLocal.withInitial(() -> Boolean.FALSE);
```

If you use a version prior to Java 8, you can’t use it that way, so the best solution in that case, is to rewrite the code to accept the default value of `null` as initial value, eliminating the need to specify a different initial value:

```
private static ThreadLocal<Boolean> inInstrumentMethod = new ThreadLocal<>();

public static void onEntry(int methodID)
{
    if (inInstrumentMethod.get()!=null) {
        return;
    } else {
        inInstrumentMethod.set(true);
    }

    System.out.println("Method ID: " + methodID);

    inInstrumentMethod.set(null);
}
```

You could also convert that anonymous inner class to a top level class. Since then, that class has no dependency to what was formerly its outer class, defining that subtype of `ThreadLocal` first, before defining the class using it, should solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks. You're exactly right! I made the inner class a proper class and it worked fine.